# Sand in Honda 2200i Generator Oil Tank

Tags: oil, oil-change, generator

So I made a really dumb mistake and forgot to inspect a funnel I used to put oil into my brand new Honda 2200i generator. After filling the oil tank I realized I had previously used the funnel to pour sand into a basketball hoop base. It wasn't enough where I obviously saw it when I first picked up the funnel, but after pulling a paper towel through the funnel I saw probably ~50-100 pieces of fine sand drop out.

I immediately drained the oil from the engine (never added gas).

Any ideas on 1) how worried I should be and 2) how I might be able to clean out the oil tank?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Your question definitely on-topic for the site! Glad you could join us :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oil filter should pick up any remaining.

If it does not have a filter then what I have done in the past is to pour a half gallon or so of diesel into the oil reservoir and give it a shake then drain that out thoroughly and refill with clean oil.

A good learning experience is to clean all tools before putting them away - then this type of thing is less likely to happen.

**I don't advise this**, but a friend used to, on all his vehicles, drain the oil, fill with diesel, run for 1 minute then drain the diesel thoroughly and fill with clean oil. His engines all ran fine, but I never did that - too impatient I suppose.

Comment: Definitely a learning experience :-(

Thanks for the reply! I'm fairly certain there is no oil filter. If I have ethanol free trufuel should I use that instead of the diesel?

Comment: Running diesel instead of oil in an engine will strip all surfaces of lubrication and cause metal on metal rubbing when it is next started. While I think this is good advice in this case I wouldn't make it a practice.

Comment: @GdD I advised giving it a shake in this case, as the OP did not run the engine there would be no need. The running was what my friend used to do and I did not.

Comment: Reading your answer may lead people to think that running diesel in place of oil as part of an oil change is a good idea, when it isn't @SolarMike.

Comment: @GdD So in your first comment you thought it was good advice and I quote " Running diesel instead of oil in an engine will strip all surfaces of lubrication and cause metal on metal rubbing when it is next started. While I think this is good advice in this case I wouldn't make it a practice". It seems you have completely changed direction, is that the case?

Comment: That wasn't clear, was it @SolarMike! What I mean is that your advice to use diesel to clean out any potential sand is good, but running the engine with diesel as part of a regular oil change isn't a good idea.

Comment: @GdD - Something you are failing to realize is *diesel is an oil*. It will provide some amount of lubrication to the bearing surfaces. If your engine is not put under load, it won't cause you issues. Again, you don't run this for very long in the engine and never under load. I don't do it today because it gives me more liquid to dispose of after an oil change. Storing, then disposing of contaminated oil is way too much fun.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, diesel is refined paraffin oil, similar to kerosene and jet fuel. Jet fuel is  more viscous  then diesel, and helps to keep jet engines lubricated which is one of it's useful properties in aviation. Diesel has less lubricating properties, you'd be better off with Jet-A1 if you can get it. Plus, it's cheaper in most places.

Comment: @GdD you said it: "Diesel has less lubricating properties" that does not mean diesel has no lubricating properties. Otherwise my injectors would have failed long before now and they are on 220K...